# Override root .htaccess to allow query string access in a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the rewrite block below in an .htaccess in the public_html root folder to protect from strange query strings and other "bad" access.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (base64_encode|localhost|mosconfig) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (GLOBALS|REQUEST)(=|\[|%) [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
```

But this breaks me running phpmyadmin in a subfolder. Specifically, phpmyadmin (not in a standalone folder, but in a WordPress plugin; but this shouldn't make a difference) is "access denied" from localhost (I think) by the `base64_encode|localhost|mosconfig` line above. I remove that line and phpmyadmin will then run in the subfolder.

What can I put in an .htaccess file in the subfolder to "clear" or override that one rule?

Comment: Why was this closed? There are 18,000+ questions on SO tagged .htaccess and 10,000+ tagged mod-rewrite. Mine is a legit question about rewrite rules in a subdirectory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an htaccess file in your phpmyadmin subfolder and put this in it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (GLOBALS|REQUEST)(=|\[|%) [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
```

That rule will have precedence over any rule in any parent folder.